# Show that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{|x-p_i|}\le 8n\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2i-1}$ for some $x,0\le x \le 1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Let $0\le p_i \le 1$ for $i = 1,2,\dots n.$ Show that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{|x-p_i|}\le 8n\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{2i-1}$ for some $x,0\le x \le 1.$

First, it seems reasonable to convert the RHS to a closed form. I know $\dfrac{\pi}{4}=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^{i-1}\dfrac{1}{2i-1},$ but I don't think that will be useful for this problem. Also, I don't think the LHS can be simplified using a telescoping series. I think I should pick several candidates $x_j$ and then take $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{1}{|x_j-p_j|}.$ I should probably also consider different intervals of $[0,1].$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assure you that everything about this problem is correct. I wouldn't have posted this if something were seriously wrong.

Comment: dude, I was asking if the right hand side is achievable, i.e., if the inequality is tight. im not asking if it's false

Comment: i still don't get what you mean. do you mean that the right hand side can be achieved (i.e. equality can be achieved)?

Comment: idk how "do you mean that the right hand side can be achieved" is much better than "is the right hand side achievable", but whatever. i am indeed asking if quality can be achieved. if not, what is the largest possibly value of the left hand side (as a function of $n$) that you currently know of?

Comment: of course it's larger. consider $p_i = \frac{i}{n}$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/902397. Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1443598.

Comment: I've modified TeX spacing so that my *Answer* displays properly on my Mac screen. Perhaps it would also on your computer screen if it didn't do so earlier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I think I should pick several candidates $x_j$

Something along those lines. Take an average. If that average is not larger than the right hand side, it follows that there is an $x$ for which the left hand side is not larger than the right hand side.

Now the question is what average we should consider. Obviously considering
$$\int_0^1 \sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{1}{\lvert x - p_j\rvert}\,dx = +\infty$$
doesn't work here.

Thus let's cut out short intervals around the $p_j$ and look at what that yields. For $0 < \varepsilon < 1$ and $p \in [0,1]$ define $A(p,\varepsilon) = \{x \in [0,1] : \lvert x - p\rvert \geqslant \varepsilon\}$, and then set
$$I(\varepsilon) = \bigcap_{j = 1}^n A(p_j,\varepsilon).$$

For small enough $\varepsilon$ this is a union of finitely many nondegenerate intervals, thus
$$M(\varepsilon) = \int_{I(\varepsilon)}dx > 0,$$
and I claim that for $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{4n}$ the average
$$\frac{1}{M(\varepsilon)} \int_{I(\varepsilon)} \sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{1}{\lvert x - p_j\rvert}\,dx$$
is no larger than $8n \sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{1}{2j-1}$, thus there are $x \in I(\varepsilon)$ satisfying the desired inequality.

First, to obtain $I(\varepsilon)$ we remove $n$ intervals of length at most $2\varepsilon$ (at most, not necessarily exactly, because there may be $p_j \in [0,\varepsilon)$ or in $(1-\varepsilon,1]$). These may overlap, so $M(\varepsilon)$ cannot be exactly determined unless the $p_j$ are explicitly given, but we have the simple bound
$$M(\varepsilon) \geqslant 1 - n\cdot 2\varepsilon,$$
in particular $M(\frac{1}{4n}) \geqslant \frac{1}{2}$.

Further, for $0 < \varepsilon \leqslant \frac{1}{4}$ and $p \in [0,1]$ we have
$$\int_{A(p,\varepsilon)} \frac{dx}{\lvert x-p\rvert} \leqslant 2\log \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}.$$
If $\varepsilon < p < 1 - \varepsilon$, then
\begin{align}
\int_{A(p,\varepsilon)} \frac{dx}{\lvert x - p\rvert}
&= \int_0^{p-\varepsilon} \frac{dx}{p-x} + \int_{p + \varepsilon}^1 \frac{dx}{x-p} \\
&= -\log \varepsilon + \log p + \log (1-p) - \log \varepsilon \\
&= 2\log \frac{1}{\varepsilon} + \log \bigl(p(1-p)\bigr) \\
&\leqslant 2\log \frac{1}{\varepsilon} + \log \frac{1}{4} \\
&= 2\log \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}
\end{align}
since $0 \leqslant p(1-p) \leqslant 1/4$.

If $0 \leqslant p \leqslant \varepsilon$, then
\begin{align}
\int_{A(p,\varepsilon)} \frac{dx}{\lvert x-p\rvert}
&= \int_{p+\varepsilon}^1 \frac{dx}{x-p} \\
&= \log (1-p) - \log \varepsilon \\
&\leqslant \log \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \\
&\leqslant 2\log \frac{1}{2\varepsilon},
\end{align}
where in the last inequality we used $\varepsilon \leqslant 1/4$. For $1 - \varepsilon \leqslant p \leqslant 1$ the claim follows similarly (by symmetry, if you want).

Thus we have, setting $\delta = \frac{1}{4n}$,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{M(\delta)}\int_{I(\delta)} \sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{1}{\lvert x - p_j\rvert}\,dx
&\leqslant 2\int_{I(\delta)} \sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{1}{\lvert x - p_j\rvert}\,dx \\
&= 2\sum_{j = 1}^n \int_{I(\delta)} \frac{dx}{\lvert x - p_j\rvert} \\
&\leqslant 2\sum_{j = 1}^n \int_{A(p_j,\delta)} \frac{dx}{\lvert x - p_j\rvert} \\
&\leqslant 2\sum_{j = 1}^n 2\log \frac{1}{2\delta} \\
&= 4n\log (2n).
\end{align}

Together with
$$\sum_{j = 1}^n \frac{2}{2j-1} \geqslant \sum_{j = 1}^n \int_{2j-1}^{2j+1} \frac{dx}{x} = \log (2n+1) > \log (2n)$$
the assertion follows.

Comment: The question cannot be closed because of the bounty, but it looks like a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/902397 to me. Here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1443598 a better bound is discussed.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR. I'll ask whether being a duplicate justifies removing the bounty.

Comment: Or perhaps close in the other direction? Both this question and your answer look far more elaborate to me.

Comment: @MartinR, my own *Answer* (see below) is elementary and straightforward. And the resulting inequality in my case is (over) 2 times sharper.

Answer (score 3):

Let

$$ \Vert x\Vert\, :=\, \min(x\,\, 1-x) $$

so that $\, \forall_{x\in[0;1]}\, \Vert x\Vert\, \le\, x\, $
and

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\Vert x-p_i\Vert}\, \ge
    \, \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{|x-p_i|} $$

> The "norm" $\, \Vert\, .\Vert\, $ is more regular (geometric, homogenous) than $\, |\ .|,\, $ and the former of the two leads useful implications about the latter one; consider $\, \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$.

With respect to $\, \Vert\, .\Vert,\, $ the unique (*up
to isometry with respect to the distance*
$\, d(x\ y):=\Vert x-y\Vert)\, $critical sequence is

$$ \forall_{k=1}^n\quad
     q_k\, :=\, \frac{2\cdot k-1}{2\cdot n} $$
and the critical $\, x\ $ is $\ x:=0\, $ (*sure,
any* $\, x:=\frac kn\, $ *would do too  (for*
$\, n=1\ldots n)\, $ where *critical* means that

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\Vert x-q_i\Vert}\, \ge
    \, \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\Vert y_m-p_i\Vert} $$

where $\, y_m\, $ provides the minimum of the RHS for the arbitrarily given sequence $\, p_1\ldots p_n\, $ (point $\, y_m\, $ depends on sequence
$\, p_k$).

Numerically, for critical values:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\Vert x-q_i\Vert}\,\, =\,
    \, 2\cdot n\cdot\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1
      {\min(2\cdot k-1,\,\ 2\cdot(n-k)+1)} $$
Obviously,

$$ 2\!\cdot\! n\cdot\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1
      {\min(2\cdot k-1,\,\ 2\cdot(n-k)+1)}\, \le
   \, 4\!\cdot\!n\cdot \sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1{2\cdot k-1} $$

This beats the required inequality over two times over.